# Convert String Number to Double and then correct format in Java

Tags: java, numbers, format

Ok so I have been searching for 2 hours on this and please before jumping to mark this as a duplicate have a look at the question.

I have a number of strings which contain number

Numbers will all be like this

```
String one = 611960;
String two = 64850;
String three = 0;
String four = 636;
```

I want to be able to have these in the correct format as in

6,119.60
648.50
0.00
6.36

I have tried

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,##0.00");
```

and converting the String to a double e.g.

```
double amount = Double.parseDouble(one);
```

which seems to give 611960.0

then I do

```
String gfeeOne = df.format(amount);
```

which in turn gives 611,960.00

So at this stage I'm a bit lost. This should be straightforward and maybe I'm getting lost. I want to cover all cases up to something like this 1000000000 e.g. 1,000,000,000.00

Help very much appreciated

Comment: Your strings are not decimals but you are expecting decimals after formatting? AFAIK, DecimalFormat is all you'd need in what I think you might be trying to do.

Comment: Look at your number ... String one = 611960;.  It doesn't have any digits and it is a whole number.  The parseDouble is doing its job.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Strings you have are interpreted as integers, as they don't have any sort of decimal separator in them (which is Locale dependent, be careful about that...). So you basically only have to divide your number by 100, or in other words, move the decimal points to the left by two places.

You should try:

```
double amount = Double.parseDouble(one)/100.0;
```

Or, even better, you could free yourself from the problems of basic floating point rounding problems, and use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

```
BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(one).movePointLeft(2);
String gfeeOne = df.format(amount);
```

**Warning** if very large values are considered, be sure to use the `BigDecimal`, as that preserves the precision, while floating point numbers can lose precision.

Comment: Ok time for a cup of tea. Thanks so much. I knew it was something small but takes someone smart to notice ;) . I presume this will work for all numbers up to a billion.

Comment: @topcat3 if very large numbers are considered, you'll have to use the BigDecimal to preserve the precision of the values represented. And don't forget that if you have a value of 1 billion, it will be interpreted as 100 billion because of the missing decimal separator, so in that case, the precision would be lost...

Answer (score 3):

You can also use String.Format:

```
String one = String.Format("%,.2f", (double)611960);
```

The `(double)` will convert the integer value to a floating point value. The format string `%,.2f` will turn a floating point number (`f`) into a string representation with two decimal points (`.2`) and add grouping separators(`,`).

Comment: In my case I need to do calculations on the figures as in add one+two+three . Would this work in that case

Comment: yep so I'll go with @ppeterka and add up my doubles. Thanks. I gave you thumbs up :)